# Empty class when generating client webservice code with wsimport

Tags: java, wsdl, jax-ws, wsimport

I am using **wsimport** to generate client web service code. (see part of wsdl code below).

Once code generation is done, I get empty TokenRequest class with no methods defined.
On the other hand, TokenResponse class has several methods defined, few setters and few getters.

**Given WSDL below, why is my TokenRequest class empty?**

I expected it to had 4 setter methods for ClientKey, Password, UserKey and UserName.
Now, I am not able to set these parameters and pass them to main Login method which receives this TokenRequest object.

I tried to create reference to this web service in .NET 4.0 and everything worked flawless. TokenRequest class had constructor that was receiving 4 paramters that I need.

**Any idea what is wrong?** Tomorrow I will try to do this using Axis2...

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    ...
                <wsdl:input name="TokenRequest">
                    **<soap12:header message="i0:TokenRequest_Headers" part="ClientKey" use="literal"/>
                    <soap12:header message="i0:TokenRequest_Headers" part="Password" use="literal"/>
                    <soap12:header message="i0:TokenRequest_Headers" part="UserKey" use="literal"/>
                    <soap12:header message="i0:TokenRequest_Headers" part="UserName" use="literal"/>
                    <soap12:body use="literal"/>**
                </wsdl:input>
                <wsdl:output name="TokenResponse">
                    <soap12:body use="literal"/>
                </wsdl:output>
     ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This secion **"4.1.4. Mapping additional WSDL headers to method parameters"** of [link](https://metro.java.net/guide/ch04.html) will explain why wsimport does not produce soap header properties you want. and there is a note in 4.1.4 section that says **"Since JAX-WS RI 2.1.3, wsimport has a new option -XadditionalHeaders, this option will map such additional headers as method parameters."** . So you should look at the documentation of library (Metro, Axis, CXF,......) and see if they have such feature.

Comment: Thanks, but -XadditionalHeaders parameter didn't change output. I still got empty class with no constructor or methods defined

Comment: May be because the version of the jax-ws (Metro) library is old (prior to 2.1.3). is there any way you can confirm what version of Metro you are using. In the mean time I will try to generate and will let you know.

Comment: I tried creating soap header using top down approach and @WebParam(header=true) annotations. It generates wsdl with soap:header and when I generate client it generates method with that extra header parameter. Now all seems easy and normal. my first question is that when you generate java from wsdl, do you see any wornings ?. Can you validate your wsdl ?.

Comment: the only warning I get is: SOAP port "LoginService": uses a non-standard SAOP 1.2 binding.    I was told to include -extension switch in wsimport and to ignore this warning...

Comment: Uh. Sorry, -XadditionalHeaders parameter did help. I just failed to notice. Thx.